# Best way to integrate database into Go Web application

Tags: mysql, web-applications, go

I'm new to developing web applications in Go.
I'm looking for the best way to integrate a MySQL database into my web application.

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
type Context struct {
     Database *sql.DB 
}
// Some database methods like Close() and Query() for Context struct here
```

In the main function for my web application I would have something like this:

```
db := sql.Open(...)
ctx := Context{db}
```

I would then pass then pass my `Context` structure into various handlers that require a database connection. Would this be a good design decision or is there a better way to integrate a SQL database into my web application?

Comment: This question seems really opinion-based. Are you asking if code you haven't written will work? For guidelines, just search the web for examples. The best questions provide a specific code example and have a clear problem to solve.

Comment: Most frameworks and samples just use a global variable, yes.

Answer (score 3):

I typically do something like this:

```
package main

func main(){
    db,err := sql.Open(...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
    http.HandleFunc("/feed", server.FeedHandler(db))
    http.HandleFunc("/gui", server.GuiHandler(db))
    ...
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}
```

Where `server` is a separate package where I define, implement and test all my http handlers.

This is basically what you were thinking of but skipping the step of wrapping the db in a struct which isn't necessary. I would **not** recommend making the db a global variable. Having global dependencies will completely destroy any possibility of testing your http handlers in a reliable fashion.

Dependency injecting the db, as in the example above, costs you two extra characters to type every time you call the function but it allows you to test your http handlers easily using the [go-sqlmock package](http://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock) which you definitely want to do as your web app grows.

```
package server

func TestFeedHandler(t *testing.T){
    mockdb, err := sqlmock.New()
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("An error '%s' was not expected when opening a stub database connection", err)
    }

    columns := []string{"id", "name"}
    sqlmock.ExpectQuery("SELECT id,name from persons;").
        WillReturnRows(sqlmock.NewRows(columns).
        AddRow(1234, "bob")

   handler := FeedHandler(mockdb)

   // test that handler returns expected result

}
```